# Converting List wrapper to List using JAXB

Tags: java, json, jaxb, cxf, binding

I'm trying to annotate a set of data objects with JAXB binding annotations so that this set of data objects can be properly marshaled as JSON using CXF.  I'm running into an issue with a class that is basically just a wrapper around ArrayList:

```
class IntegerListWrapper {
    private ArrayList<Integer> integerList;
    ...
}
```

Some of my data objects refer to this class:

```
class DataObjectFoo {
    ...
    public IntegerListWrapper getDataIDs() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm looking for the output to be:

```
"DataObjectFoo" : {
  "dataIDs" : [1, 2, ..., n] // Array of Data IDs
}
```

I tried annotating the IDList class itself but it left me with this:

```
"DataObjectFoo" : {
  "dataIDs" : { "integerList" : [1, 2, ..., n] } // Extra nesting
}
```

I tried writing an XmlAdapter but got mixed results:

```
// Throws an error... "Can't bind to interface"
public final class IDListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List<Integer>, IDList> {
// Does not produce any output
public final class IDListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ArrayList<Integer>, IDList> {
// Produces output with extra nesting like above
public final class IDListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Integer[]>, IDList>
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I get the desired output (without converting IDList to something else in my data objects)?
2. Why did the second XmlAdapter (using ArrayList) not produce output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can with the extra wrapper class around it.    Can you not just make the "getDataIds()" call return List?

Comment: The Integer wrapper class is used by many external sources so I was hoping to avoid changing that.  I tried using an XmlAdapter (extends XmlAdapter<String, IDList>).  This gave me the format I was looking for but it was a string and not an integer array.  I'm still holding out hope (for a little longer) that there's a way to do this.